# cp and rsync cannot find system directory

Tags: osx-mavericks, rsync, cp

I am working on a script to copy a custom user profile over to the default. Part of the script uses rsync to copy the contents of the customized profile, named "profile" to the default profile located in: /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj. Each time I run the command interactively, it fails indicating "No such file or directory." I can browse to the directory in the Finder. I can navigate to the directory via the terminal. Why can't rsync find it? Here is the command:

```
rsync -av /Users/profile/* /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj
```

I tried a similar approach using `cp -R` instead of rsync and got a whole bunch of file not found error messages. Using the `cd` command to that same path also fails. I can step through each individual directory and arrive at English.lproj but I can't do it in one command. Any ideas where I am going wrong with my command?

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Have you tried to surround the path with spaces with quotes and remove the backslash? `rsync -av /Users/profile/* '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj`

Comment: Do you mean to surround the entire path with a single quote at the beginning and end? I did try that with double quotes but not single quotes. Thanks